# Execute remote commands on an SSH with Java?

Tags: java, ssh, chilkat

I am trying to write java code to execute remote commands on an SSH, similar to the one in this library: [Chilkat Android SSH Execute Remote Commands](https://www.example-code.com/android/ssh_execute_remote_commands.asp).

However, I do not know where to begin. I do not need to implement the entire library, I only need to be able to send messages from my computer to a device through a SSH using Java code. Specifically I want to implement the `Connect`, `AuthenticatePw` and `quickCommand` methods in the library.

My question is what do I need to learn in order to be able to write a java file that does this? I would appreciate any links to relevant tutorials.